# Send data from C# 4.0 to VLC using pipe

Tags: c#-4.0, pipe, vlc

I am trying to send the video flow from a C# program to VLC and I do not arrive to link both applications...
Note: the applications are running on the same computer.

I use this code in C# to declare the Pipe Server in C#

`NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out);
pipeServer.WaitForConnection();`

FYI: I have develop a Pipe client in C# to test the Pipe Server and they work together.

My pipe name is "truc".

In VLC I try open the player using

`vlc -`

`vlc fd://truc`

`vlc stream://truc`

`vlc stream://\.\pipe\truc`

`vlc file://truc`

`vlc file://\.\pipe\truc`

but always the same error: VLC can not open "...".

Is someone known where I am wrong ?

Thanks
Josselin

Answer (score 4):

```
vlc.exe stream://\\\.\pipe\truc
```

Don't ask me why but with this amount of slashes my VLC is perfectly happy.

Comment: ffplay is very nice by the way: "ffplay \\.\pipe\truc" is enough.